# List to dictionary mapping Python

Tags: python

I am looking for guidance/assistants on python. I am no expert and this is this first time for me.

The question is:

Given a list of parameter names and a list of numeric values, create a dictionary mapping names to values.

```
def get_params(sparams):
    r"""
    Input: sparams : str
    Output: params : dict
    >>> get_params("atoms = 100")
    {'atoms': 100.0}
    >>> get_params("dt = 0.001\n" \
    ...           +"temp = 300\n")
    {'dt': 0.001, 'temp': 300.0}
    >>> get_params("press = 10\n" \
    ...           +"vol   = 220\n")
    {'press': 10.0, 'vol': 220.0}
    >>> get_params("dt = 0.002\n" \
    ...           +"N  = 3000\n" \
    ...           +"temp  = 320\n" \
    ...           +"press = 1\n" \
    ...           +"L     = 20\n")
    {'press': 1.0, 'dt': 0.002, 'L': 20.0, 'temp': 320.0, 'N': 3000.0}
    """
$#return {'dt': 0.001, 'N': 400.0}
```

This is the format the sample value should display afterwards.

I was able to contruct this but it puts the single quotes on the numerical value

```
#    dictionary=sparams
#    mydict = {}
#    listKey = []
#    listValue = []
#    for line in dictionary.split("\n"):
#        if not line.strip():
#           continue
#       k, v = [word.strip() for word in line.split("=")]
#        mydict[k] = v
```

Comment: You need to convert the string to an int or double, using those functions: `double("0.002")` and `int("20")`, for example.

Comment: can you post clearly what is your expected output ?

Comment: RdR, Answered the question. The problem was my v value was a string and should ahve been converted into a float/int. The expected output was at the end of the first code block.

Answer (score 1):

You have got very close, but you are saving your value `v` as a string. You need to convert it to a numeric value. If you edit your last line to `mydict[k] = float(v)` then I think it should work.